# Word very slow openig file from file server share

Tags: microsoft-word, file-sharing

Internet is full of useless advises on how to solve speed problem with Word.
My problem has some unique characteristics, I did some tests and I need a focused hint on what to try next.

Some users have an old version of Word (I cannot update due to missing licenses) and when they try to open small files (about 20 KB) on a network share (Windows 2016 server) it takes more than 3 minutes.

They don't experience the same delay opening local files or files on other shares.

Users with a newer release of Word can open files on the above mentioned Windows 2016 server ion a reasonable amount of time.

I cannot understand why the old Word doesn't like that particular file share. Apparently it has nothing special. How can I investigate further ?

**Update**

It seems that Word makes very numerous read operations of few bytes to Windows 2016 server. Copying the same file to a different share the read operations are reduced drastically (they become bigger). If this behavior is confirmed by other tests it can explain the great delay, anyway I don't know what to check on the file servers.

Thanks
Filippo